# Multi class object in R

Tags: r, class, dplyr

I've recently started utilizing the dplyr package for data manipulation but don't have a complete grasp on the output of group_by(). In the example below how can my single iris.2 object have 4 different classes? How does the function know which class to use? IE if I call print it will call the print.tbl_df method and not the print.data.frame.

```
library(dplyr)
iris.1 <- iris
iris.2 <- group_by(iris, Species)
class(iris.1)
```

[1] "data.frame"

```
class(iris.2)
```

[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Comment: You might want to skim http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s3

Answer (score 5):

The `class` function returns the complete inheritance of the object.  In your example, `iris.2` is first an object of the class `grouped_df`. Any methods for the `grouped_df` class will take precedent.  Next, it is a `tbl_df` class, then a `tbl` class and finally a `data.frame`.  When calling a method such as `print`, R will look for the `print` method of these classes in that order and will use the first it encounters.